# Can't figure out how to return one of three values based on two numbers

Tags: c#

I'm making a rating element with stars indicating the average rating and need code that returns either an EmptyStar, HalfStar or FullStar. FullStar was easy, but I'm stuck on the rest.

The value *currentCount* will be from 1 to 5 and *sum* is the average rating.

**Code**:

```
string fa = string.Empty;

if (sum >= currentCount)
{
    fa = FullFaStar;
}
else if (???)
{
    fa = HalfFaStar;
}
else if (???)
{
    fa = EmptyFaStar;
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of "half star" and "empty star"?

Comment: @lurker let's say the rating is 3.7 then I want four full stars, rounding up if the decimal is bigger than 5. if not I want a half star. if that makes any sense

Comment: So if it is 3.2 it should be 3 stars. 3.5 equals to 3 full stars and a half star and 3.6 then equals to 4 full stars?

Comment: @Marco yes exactly!

Comment: What represents currentCount? I think you only need the average.

Comment: @Alpha75 currentCount represents the index of the five stars. I thought I could loop 5 times and get the correct star tag and only need to pass in average rating and the current star to return

Comment: Forget about the implementation and the code, what is the **definition** of those stars? If you were to explain this to a non-programmer, what would you say?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is you are looking for:

```
private static string FullFaStar = "full";
private static string HalfFaStar = "half";
private static string EmptyFaStar = "empty";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {0}");
    GetStarts(0);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {0.5m}");
    GetStarts(0.5m);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {0.8m}");
    GetStarts(0.8m);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {2.4m}");
    GetStarts(2.4m);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {3.2m}");
    GetStarts(3.2m);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {4.5m}");
    GetStarts(4.5m);
    Console.WriteLine($"Value {5m}");
    GetStarts(5m);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string GetStarts(decimal sum)
{
    string fa = string.Empty;
    for (int currentCount = 0; currentCount < 5; currentCount++)
    {

        if ((sum - currentCount) >= 1m)
        {
            fa = FullFaStar;
        }
        else if ((sum - currentCount) >= 0.5m)
        {
            fa = HalfFaStar;
        }
        else if (((sum - currentCount) < 0.5m))
        {
            fa = EmptyFaStar;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"start {currentCount}: {fa}");

    }
    return fa;
}
```

Result:

```
Value 0
start 0: empty
start 1: empty
start 2: empty
start 3: empty
start 4: empty
Value 0,5
start 0: half
start 1: empty
start 2: empty
start 3: empty
start 4: empty
Value 0,8
start 0: half
start 1: empty
start 2: empty
start 3: empty
start 4: empty
Value 2,4
start 0: full
start 1: full
start 2: empty
start 3: empty
start 4: empty
Value 3,2
start 0: full
start 1: full
start 2: full
start 3: empty
start 4: empty
Value 4,5
start 0: full
start 1: full
start 2: full
start 3: full
start 4: half
Value 5
start 0: full
start 1: full
start 2: full
start 3: full
start 4: full
```

Comment: yes almost, it gave me one full star and four empty for a rating of 1.5. but I should be able to tweak it. thanks!

Comment: Yes, it had a mistake. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some "custom" fixes, but it works as expected.

**Code**:

```
string fa = EmptyFaStar;
double tmp = (sum - currentCount).Decimals();

if (!tmp.IsPositive())
{
    tmp = tmp * -1;
}

if (sum >= currentCount)
{
    fa = FullFaStar;
}
else if (tmp >= 0.5)
{
    fa = HalfFaStar;
}
else if (tmp < 0.5)
{
    fa = EmptyFaStar;
}

if (last.Equals(HalfFaStar) && fa.Equals(HalfFaStar))
{
    fa = EmptyFaStar;
}
else if (last.Equals(EmptyFaStar) && !fa.Equals(EmptyFaStar))
{
    fa = EmptyFaStar;
}

last = fa;
```